# "Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'f' in -f5" when running bash script from Python

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, kubernetes-helm

I'm having an issue running a simple `python` script that reads a `helm` command from a `.sh` script and outputs it.

When I run the command directly in the terminal, it runs fine:

```sh
helm list | grep prod- | cut -f5

# OUTPUT: prod-L2.0.3.258
```

But when I run `python test.py` (see below for whole source code of `test.py`), I get an error as if the command I'm running is `helm list -f5` and not `helm list | grep prod- | cut -f5`:

```sh
user@node1:$ python test.py

# OUTPUT:
# Opening file 'helm_chart_version.sh' for reading...
# Running command 'helm list | grep prod- | cut -f5'...
# Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'f' in -f5
```

The `test.py` script:

```py
import subprocess

# Open file for reading
file = "helm_chart_version.sh"

print("Opening file '" + file + "' for reading...")
bashCommand = ""
with open (file) as fh: 
    next(fh) 
    bashCommand = next(fh)

print("Running command '" + bashCommand + "'...")

process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = process.communicate()

if error is None:
    print output
else:
    print error
```

Contents of `helm_chart_version.sh`:

```sh
cat helm_chart_version.sh

#  OUTPUT: 
## !/bin/bash
## helm list | grep prod- | cut -f5
```

Comment: Don't split your command, and use `shell=True` in the `Popen` command: `process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`.

Comment: Explanation: pipes are a shell feature, so if you don't process the command through a shell, those vertical-bars are just weird-looking arguments to the `helm` command.

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid running complex shell pipelines from higher-level languages.  Given the command you show, you can run `helm list` as a subprocess, and then do the post-processing on it in Python.

```python
process = subprocess.run(["helm", "list"], capture_output=True, text=True, check=True)
for line in process.stdout.splitlines():
  if 'prod-' not in line:
    continue
  words = line.split()
  print(words[4])
```

The actual Python script you show doesn't seem to be semantically different from just directly running the shell script.  You can use the `sh -x` option or the shell `set -x` command to cause it to print out each line as it executes.